# Costum script just stopped working. No changes made

Tags: python, scripting, import

I downloaded some python scripts to import models and maps from the game Dishonored 2 which worked great at first.

Today, I wanted to continue looking at models and maps but the script just stopped working.

Below is the error it gives me. Any idea what that means?

Thanks in advance :D

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.1\scripts\addons\io_scene_Dishonored2\__init__.py", line 231, in execute
    result = modbuilder.build_model(context.collection, filepath)
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.1\scripts\addons\io_scene_Dishonored2\models.py", line 624, in build_model
    self.instantiate_descriptor(name, info, meshes, desc, objects)
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.1\scripts\addons\io_scene_Dishonored2\models.py", line 578, in instantiate_descriptor
    check_object_invisible(obj)
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.1\scripts\addons\io_scene_Dishonored2\materials.py", line 143, in check_object_invisible
    obj.cycles_visibility.shadow = False
AttributeError: 'Object' object has no attribute 'cycles_visibility'

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

Comment: The addon caused a bugs, try to contact the author.

Comment: The addon needs to be updated for 3.0 API when they changed the `cycles_visibility` property

Comment: Based on what @Gorgious said, I would install Blender 3.0 and re-install the add-on.